# Insert into SQL - records gets written twice

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a program that is Access 2010 front end and a SQL Server database as back end.
I wrote a routine that inserts a record into SQL Server.

Here is the code:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [dbo_phoneno] (dtstamp, who, what,  sortorder, company, typephoneno, name, wphone, cphone, mob) " _
   & "VALUES(" _
   & "'" & pubDTStamp & "'," _
   & "'" & pubWho & "'," _
   & "'" & pubWhat & "'," _
   & "'" & pubSortOrder & "'," _
   & "'" & pubCompany & "'," _
   & "'" & pubType & "'," _
   & "'" & pubName & "'," _
   & "'" & pubWphone & "'," _
   & "'" & pubCphone & "'," _
   & "'" & pubMob & "') "
```

The code works fine except when I exit out of the program the record is written out again.  I checked the code but do not see where it can be.  Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Can you check if there is a setting for running you DoCmd at file exit?

Answer (score 0):

Either your code gets executed twice or you have a trigger somewhere that does the additional `INSERT`.

Use [Sql Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) and run a trace. You'll be able to find from where the second `INSERT` comes from. If it's not from a trigger, then you'll have to set a breakpoint in your app and run it in debug mode.